# What is the correct way to use ui-calendar with Urigo's angular-meteor?

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I want to use ui-calendar with Urigo's angular-meteor. I code like this, it doesn't work but I don't  know why and how to fix it.
The collection is not empty but event do not appear in calendar. Thank you for attention. 
https://github.com/wuxianliang/ui-calendar-angular-meteor

```
CalEvents = new Mongo.Collection("calevents");
CalEvents.allow({
    insert: function () {
        return true;
    },
    update: function () {
        return true;
    },
    remove: function () {
        return true;
    }
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {

angular.module('Calendardemo', ['angular-meteor', 'ui.calendar','ui.router', 'angularMoment','mgcrea.ngStrap','ngAnimate']);

Meteor.startup(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['Calendardemo']);
});

angular.module('Calendardemo').controller('MyCalendar', [
    '$scope',
    '$collection',
    function($scope, $collection) {
        $collection(CalEvents).bind($scope,'calevents',true,true);


        $scope.addCalEvent=function(date, jsEvent, view){
            var startDateTime = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ');
            var endDateTime = moment(date).add(1, 'h').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ');
            $scope.calevents.push({
                title: 'New Event',
                start: startDateTime,
                end: endDateTime,
                completed: null,
                doing: null
            })

        };
        $scope.eventRender = function(event,element){};
        /* config object */
        $scope.uiConfig = {
            calendar:{
                height: 450,
                defaultView: 'month',
                lang: 'en',
                eventColor: 'grey',
                header:{
                    left: 'prev next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month agendaWeek'
                },
                dayClick: $scope.addCalEvent,
                eventRender: $scope.eventRender,
                editable: true,
                selectable: true,
                allDayDefault: false
            }
        };
        $scope.eventSources = [$scope.calevents];
    }]);}
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('calevents', function(){
        return CalEvents.find();
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this package:
https://github.com/netanelgilad/meteor-angular-ui-calendar

This package wraps angular-ui-calendar for Meteor.

It might not updated so you can open an issue inside

***EDIT***

You might also want to check out this package that looks more updated:
https://atmospherejs.com/planettraining/angular-ui-calendar