# npm ERR! 404 Not Found npm ERR! not ok code 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, meteor, angular-meteor

I've just started making a website with [angular-meteor](http://angular-meteor.com/) in which I now want to use a calendar to select a date. From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27090690/1650012) I got the tip to checkout [meteor-angular-ui-calendar](https://github.com/planet-training/meteor-angular-ui-calendar/) which I installed using

```
meteor add angularui:ui-calendar
```

After installing the app however, my app crashes with a message saying `Error: Can't find npm module 'bcrypt'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'npm-bcrypt' package?`. So I tried installing that using the following variations

```
npm install npm-brcrypt
npm install brcrypt
```

Unfortunately I always get an error saying

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I tried some of the thing suggested in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920571/cant-install-any-packages-in-node-js-using-npm-install), but nothing helped.

Does anybody know what's wrong and how I can fix this? All tips are welcome!

Comment: There is no `brcrypt` module. Could it just be a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I already found it.

I should have read 3 lines further on, which said:

> Important: Include FullCalendar if the source is missing in your app:
>
> ```
> meteor add planettraining:jquery-fullcalendar
> ```

That fixed it.

I wish you all a beautiful day!